# How to read content of wp_editor using jquery

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

I am using wp_editor. I added require class as editor_class. Here is the rendered html:

```
<fieldset class="frontier_post_fieldset">
    <legend>বিস্তারিত</legend>
    <div id="frontierpost" class="input-group require" data-require-min="1">
        <div id="wp-frontier_post_content-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap tmce-active">
            <link rel="stylesheet" id="editor-buttons-css" href="http://localjegeachi.com/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css?ver=4.9.4" type="text/css" media="all">
            <div id="wp-frontier_post_content-editor-tools" class="wp-editor-tools hide-if-no-js">
                <div id="wp-frontier_post_content-media-buttons" class="wp-media-buttons">
                    <button type="button" id="insert-media-button" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="frontier_post_content">
                        <span class="wp-media-buttons-icon"></span> Add Media
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="wp-editor-tabs">
                    <button type="button" id="frontier_post_content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="frontier_post_content">Visual</button>
                    <button type="button" id="frontier_post_content-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="frontier_post_content">Text</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="wp-frontier_post_content-editor-container" class="wp-editor-container form-group">
                <div id="qt_frontier_post_content_toolbar" class="quicktags-toolbar">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_strong" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Bold" value="b">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_em" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Italic" value="i">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_link" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Insert link" value="link">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_block" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Blockquote" value="b-quote">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_del" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Deleted text (strikethrough)" value="del">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_ins" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Inserted text" value="ins">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_img" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Insert image" value="img">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_ul" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Bulleted list" value="ul">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_ol" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Numbered list" value="ol">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_li" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="List item" value="li">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_code" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Code" value="code">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_more" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Insert Read More tag" value="more">
                    <input type="button" id="qt_frontier_post_content_close" class="ed_button button button-small" title="Close all open tags" value="close tags">
                </div>
                <div id="mceu_24" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="application" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px; width: 100%;">
                    <div id="mceu_24-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout">
                        <div id="mceu_25" class="mce-toolbar-grp mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-first" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group">
                            <div id="mceu_25-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout">
                                <div id="mceu_26" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item mce-first" role="toolbar">
                                    <div id="mceu_26-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout">
                                        <div id="mceu_27" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-last mce-btn-group" role="group">
                                            <div id="mceu_27-body">
                                                <div id="mceu_0" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-menubtn mce-fixed-width mce-listbox mce-first mce-btn-has-text" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_0" role="button" aria-haspopup="true">
                                                    <button id="mceu_0-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <span class="mce-txt">Paragraph</span>
                                                        <i class="mce-caret"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_1" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Bold">
                                                    <button id="mceu_1-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-bold"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_2" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Italic">
                                                    <button id="mceu_2-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-italic"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_3" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Bulleted list">
                                                    <button id="mceu_3-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-bullist"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_4" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Numbered list">
                                                    <button id="mceu_4-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-numlist"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_5" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Blockquote">
                                                    <button id="mceu_5-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-blockquote"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_6" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Align left">
                                                    <button id="mceu_6-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-alignleft"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_7" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Align center">
                                                    <button id="mceu_7-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-aligncenter"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_8" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Align right">
                                                    <button id="mceu_8-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-alignright"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_9" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Insert/edit link">
                                                    <button id="mceu_9-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-link"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_10" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Insert Read More tag">
                                                    <button id="mceu_10-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-wp_more"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_11" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Fullscreen">
                                                    <button id="mceu_11-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-fullscreen"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_12" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Toolbar Toggle">
                                                    <button id="mceu_12-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-wp_adv"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="mceu_28" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item mce-last" role="toolbar" style="display: none;">
                                    <div id="mceu_28-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout">
                                        <div id="mceu_29" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-last mce-btn-group" role="group">
                                            <div id="mceu_29-body">
                                                <div id="mceu_13" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Strikethrough">
                                                    <button id="mceu_13-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-strikethrough"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_14" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Horizontal line">
                                                    <button id="mceu_14-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-hr"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_15" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-colorbutton" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Text color">
                                                    <button role="presentation" hidefocus="1" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-forecolor"></i>
                                                        <span id="mceu_15-preview" class="mce-preview"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="mce-open" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-caret"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_16" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Paste as text">
                                                    <button id="mceu_16-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-pastetext"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_17" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Clear formatting">
                                                    <button id="mceu_17-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-removeformat"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_18" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Special character">
                                                    <button id="mceu_18-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-charmap"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_19" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Decrease indent">
                                                    <button id="mceu_19-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-outdent"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_20" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Increase indent">
                                                    <button id="mceu_20-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-indent"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_21" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Undo" aria-disabled="false">
                                                    <button id="mceu_21-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-undo"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_22" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-disabled" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Redo" aria-disabled="true">
                                                    <button id="mceu_22-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-redo"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="mceu_23" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-label="Keyboard Shortcuts">
                                                    <button id="mceu_23-button" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1">
                                                        <i class="mce-ico mce-i-wp_help"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mceu_30" class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;">
                            <iframe id="frontier_post_content_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press Alt-Shift-H for help." style="width: 100%; height: 300px; display: block;"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mceu_31" class="mce-statusbar mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-last" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;">
                            <div id="mceu_31-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout">
                                <div id="mceu_32" class="mce-path mce-flow-layout-item mce-first">
                                    <div role="button" class="mce-path-item mce-last" data-index="0" tabindex="-1" id="mceu_32-0" aria-level="1">p</div>
                                </div>
                                <span id="mceu_55" class="mce-wordcount mce-widget mce-label mce-flow-layout-item">Words: 1</span>
                                <div id="mceu_33" class="mce-flow-layout-item mce-resizehandle mce-last">
                                    <i class="mce-ico mce-i-resize"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <textarea class="require wp-editor-area form-control" style="height: 300px; display: none;" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="frontier_post_content" id="frontier_post_content" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hestiaEditorInlineStyle( ed ) {
                ed.onInit.add( function() {

                        // Added custom CSS in editor.
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addStyle("body.mce-content-body a { color: #e91e63; }");
                    } );
            };
        </script>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

I want to read content of the textarea input having require class as follows:

```
$('.submit_btn').click(function(event){

        $('.require').each(function(){
            THIS = $(this); // THIS - global variable. if THIS is followed by 'var' it willl be local here
            console.log('value : '+THIS.val());
            validate();
        });

        submitORnot(event);
    });
```

But it does not work. Is there any other approach to read the content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official documentation at https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent:

You can use one of these:

> ```
> // Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
> console.debug(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
>
> // Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
> tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'raw'});
>
> // Get content of a specific editor:
> tinymce.get('content id').getContent()
> ```

So in your case, try this:

```
$('.submit_btn').click(function(event){
    $('.require').each(function(){
        THIS = $(this); // THIS - global variable. if THIS is followed by 'var' it willl be local here
        //var value = tinymce.get( THIS.attr( 'id' ) ).getContent(); // Get the HTML content.
        var value = tinymce.get( THIS.attr( 'id' ) ).getContent( { format: 'text' } );
        console.log('value : '+value);
        validate();
    });

    submitORnot(event);
});
```